# Having an issue with input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made a function that gets a list of integers from the user and bubble sort them.
This is the error i get:

> "input2= input("Please enter some numbers separated by backspace: ")
>   File "", line 1 1 0 3 2 5 4"

```
def ex2():
    list2= []
    input2= input("Please enter some numbers separated by backspace: ")
    list2_input = input2.split()

    for i in list2_input:
        list2.append(i)

    for i in range(0, len(list2)-1):
        for j in range(0, len(list2)- 1 - i):
            list2[j], list2[j] = list2[j+1], list2[j]
    print list2
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2.7, `input` takes the input from the user and runs `eval` on it. If the text is not a valid Python expression, it will crash.

"1 0 3 2 5 4" is not a valid Python expression, so if the user enters that at an `input` prompt, it will crash.

To take input from the user without `eval`ing it, use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Answer (score 1):

if you do not want any automatic evaluation on your input use:

```
raw_input("Please enter some numbers separated by backspace: ")
```

this is a problem you will only have in Python 2.7 as the 2.7 `raw_input` has been renamed `input` in Python 3.

if you call input in Python 2.7 this will call:

```
eval(raw_input("Please enter some numbers separated by backspace: "))
```

and as you can see on the following link:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval
`evals` evaluate checks that the expression argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression.

Answer (score 0):

input(...) Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).

So use raw_input instead or input `"1 0 3 2 4 5"` include double quotation marks。